# HTML Link Relationship

Tags: html, relationship, meta-tags

I seem to remember at one point there was a proposed schema for adding meaningful relationship information in the "a" tag. Info like "type of friend" or "Relationship". Maybe it was an extension of REL but I don't think so. Anyone remember this effort and if it was widely adopted or even useful?

Answer (score 1):

XFN - Xhtml Friends Network: http://gmpg.org/xfn/

Comment: Was it widely adopted or even useful? (I'm guessing **No** with a capital "N", in bold text)

Comment: At least the rel="me" tag is used everywhere. The others.. not so much, sadly.